# Question deleted after answering

Tags: discussion

So I answered a question correctly and the OP deleted the question after realising the answer. Is this supposed to happen? What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: In addition to the linked post from the comment above, you can probably prevent it by not answering crappy questions.

Comment: @Oleg are you making a sweeping statement there or are you aware of the question the OP is talking about?

Comment: @JonClements Just a general statement. It's much more likely to happen when you answer a bad question. Sorry, should've made it more clear.

Comment: It just happened to me too... 
Should did not have, at least, a negative impact on the user who asked,and deleted, the question, just to make sure there is more thinking before asking?